# Heap use after free that i don't understand

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition, address-sanitizer

I know from previous C projects that ASAN tells me "heap-use-after-free" when I try to access to a pointer after the use offree() but in this case I don't even understand because i use free() at the end of the main and do nothing after.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define URL "URL"
#define API_KEY "KEY"

void add_parameter(char *query, char *key, char *value)
{
    const size_t new_len = strlen(query) + strlen(key) + strlen(value) + 3; 
    query = realloc(query, new_len * sizeof(char));
    if (query)
    {
        strcat(query, "?");
        strcat(query, key);
        strcat(query, "=");
        strcat(query, value);
        query[new_len - 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", query);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *query = malloc((strlen(URL) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(query, URL, sizeof(URL));

    add_parameter(query, "api_key", API_KEY);
    printf("%s\n", query);
    free(query);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

For starters the pointer `query` is passed to the function `add_parameter` by value

```
add_parameter(query, "api_key", API_KEY);
```

It means that the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer `query` within the function.

Changing the copy does not reflect on the original pointer `query`. The original pointer `query` passed to the function by value stays unchanged.

You need to pass the pointer by reference.

Passing by reference in C means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Dereferencing the pointer you will have a direct access to the original object.

In this case the function will be declared like

```
int add_parameter(char **query, const char *key, const char *value);
```

(as the strings pointed to by the parameters `key` and `value` are not changed within the function the parameters should be declared with the qualifier `const`) and within the function you have to write

```
int add_parameter( char **query, const char *key, const char *value )
{
    const size_t new_len = strlen( query ) + strlen( key ) + strlen( value ) + 3; 
    char *tmp = realloc( query, new_len * sizeof( char ) ); 

    int success = tmp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        strcat( rmp, "?" );
        strcat( tmp, key );
        strcat( tmp, "=" );
        strcat( tmp, value );
        printf("%s\n", tmp);
   
        *query = tmp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

This statement within the function

```
tmp[new_len - 1] = '\0';
```

is redundant. So it is removed

Pay attention to that `realloc` can return a null-pointer. In this case if not to use the intermediate variable `tmp` the early allocated memory can be lost.

The function can be called like

```
add_parameter( &query, "api_key", API_KEY);
```

or

```
if ( add_parameter( &query, "api_key", API_KEY) )
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following line can cause a problem

```
query = realloc(query, new_len * sizeof(char));
```

As the value of `query` could change. It, `main`. it is unaware of this change. Pass the updated version of `query` back to `main`.

Comment: Thanks, so if I modify a pointer somewhere, I always need to return it in order to free it correctly ?

Comment: That is correct